# L'absence du mot « pas » dans une tournure négative

Tags: grammaire, négation, adverbes

Je voudrais savoir avec quels verbes on peut ne pas utiliser le mot *pas*.

Par exemple:

> Je ne sais comment vous remercier.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a list-based response.  List questions are usually not a good fit for SE.

Comment: @Patrick: You are somewhat right, but for this kind of question an answer can also explain what are the categories of verbs that are part of the list. And I'm kind of disappointed that this question was closed as a duplicate, because I believe that only a small set of verbs, among which *pouvoir* and *savoir*, are commonly used without *pas* (and only in specific circumstances)… I'd really like to know what are those verbs and why.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Fair enough.  I didn't vote to close it as a duplicate, as I did not believe it was a duplicate.  Someone start a discussion on meta if they want to talk about it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Le fait de ne pas utiliser le mot *pas* relève plus du registre de langue que d'une liste limitée de verbes. En théorie, tous les verbes peuvent se mettre sous cette forme, c'est juste que certains sonneront plus bancals que d'autres à l'oreille.

Il est amusant de voir que selon le registre, c'est un élément ou un autre de la négation qui est omis.

Registre soutenu

> Je **ne** sais comment vous remercier

Registre courant

> Je **ne** sais **pas** comment vous remercier

Registre familier

> Je sais **pas** comment vous/te remercier

Answer (score 1):

Pour rappel l'utilisation du « pas » est directement lié au sens de la phrase bien plus qu'aux verbes.

Les affirmations n'utilisent pas le « pas » alors que les négations peuvent aussi utiliser « plus ».

Exemples:

> Pierre n'a plus envie
>
> Pierre n'a jamais eu envie
>
> Pierre ne veut plus
>
> Pierre ne veut pas
>
> Pierre n'envie jamais

Ces deux formules doivent être fausses grammaticalement. C'est utilisé par des romanciers ou dans la *vie de tous les jours* lorsque le temps avale des syllabes.

> Je ne sais **pas** comment vous remercier?

Il ne faut pas répondre, c'est un cadeau.

> Ils ne pouvaient **plus** espérer mieux .

C'est un oxymore.

Comment: Pourquoi "*Ils ne pouvaient plus espérer mieux.*" serait un oxymore?