# Peut-on omettre « ne » avant « que » en francais informel ?

Tags: négation, registre-familier

En français informel, il est commun d'exprimer une négation sans la particule *ne* comme : 
*j'ai pas d'argent*. Ce n'est pas uniquement avec le mot *pas* que l'on omet le mot *ne*, on l'omet également avec *plus*, *rien*, *jamais*…

Dans la négation suivante : *je n'ai que deux mains*, est-t-il possible de dire en français informel : *j'ai que deux mains* ?

Comment: À l'oral, et dans un langage relativement familier alors...

Comment: Déjà posée : [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/135/jai-bien-peur-que-tu-naies-raison-faut-il-mettre-le-mot-ne) ou [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6604/quelle-est-la-difference-entre-ne-ne-pas-et-pas) ou encore [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7402/labsence-du-mot-pas-dans-une-tournure-negative)

Comment: Ces sont de 'ne expletif', pas de 'ne....que'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui. La tournure « ne ... que » pour signifier « seulement » est une tournure négative, du point de vue de la grammaire. La règle pour omettre le *ne* est la même qu'avec les particules qui ont une valeur négative sémantiquement : on peut l'omettre à l'oral, dans un registre familier.

> J'ai pas le temps.
>   J'ai jamais vu un truc pareil.
>   J'ai que deux mains.

Quelques manières très informelles (mais pas grossières) de dire « je ne comprends rien » :

> Je pige rien. = Je capte pas. = J'entrave [que dalle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dalle).

(Je déconseille ces expressions pour un locuteur non natif qui n'est pas déjà très aisé en français. Se contenter de « je ne comprends pas » ou à la rigueur « je comprends pas ».)

Pour dire « j'ai déjà les mains pleines, je ne peux rien porter d'autre », la tournure idiomatique est « j'ai pas trois mains ».

Comment: Pourriez-vous expliciter les similarités et différences entre `je ne peux rien porter d'autre` vs `je ne peux pas porter rien d'autre` ? Je suis désorienté car dans le premier, la negation `ne rien` est enveloppée dans le verbe `pouvoir`.

Comment: @LePressentiment « Je ne peux rien porter d'autre » est correct. « \*Je ne peux pas porter rien d'autre » n'est pas une phrase française. Le mot *ne* est avant le verbe et l'autre particule négative est après le verbe, juste après le premier verbe s'il y en a plusieurs : c'est toujours comme ça en français.

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant. Grâce à vous, je comprends maintenant que `« Je ne peux rien porter d'autre » est correct.` Néanmoins, pourquoi est-ce que `« Je ne peux pas porter rien d'autre »` est erronée ? `Ne pas` se situe justement ici, non ?

Comment: @LePressentiment *Pas* est une négation « neutre » : ce mot signifie juste une négation, rien de plus. On peut combiner des particules négatives qui ont un sens supplémentaire, par exemple *jamais* (négation d'existence dans le temps) et *rien* (négation d'existence d'une chose). Mais *pas* serait redondant avec toute autre négation, puisque il n'apporte pas de sens au-delà de la négation. Ceci explique qu'on ne peut pas combiner *pas* avec une autre particule négative.